# Генератор псевдослучайных чисел заполняет вектор одинаковыми числами

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++, случайные-числа

Вот есть генератор псевдослучайных чисел:

```
template <typename Number>
class Uniform
{
    mt19937 rng;
    uniform_real_distribution<Number> vg;

public:
    explicit Uniform(size_t seed = 5512943)
        : rng(seed), vg(Number(-1), Number(+1)) {}

    Number operator()() { return vg(rng); }
};
```

Мне нужно создать функцию, которая заполняла бы вектор через generate. Чуть ниже можно посмотреть, как я это пробовал реализовать. Ошибок нет, числа есть, проблема в том, что числа эти всегда одни и теже. Вопрос в том, как мне исправить данную ситуацию?

```
    template <typename RanIT> // RanIT тип итератора
    void vector_filling(RanIT from, RanIT to, size_t n)
    {
        Uniform <double> gen;
        for (auto it = from; it < to; ++it)
        {
            it->resize(n);
            generate(it->begin(), it->end(), gen);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Ну может потому что `seed` всегда одинаковый??? `size_t seed = 5512943`

Comment: Но, если, я использую этот генератор в такой функции, он заполняется случайными числами template <typename RanIT>
void vector_filling(RanIT from, RanIT to, size_t n, Uniform <double>& gen)
{
    for (auto it = from; it < to; ++it)
    {
        vector <double> coordinates(n);
        for (size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i)
            coordinates[i] = gen();
        *it = coordinates;
    }
}

Answer (score 1):

Инициализируйте свой генератор *случайным* значением так:

```
explicit Uniform(size_t seed = random_device()())
```

Только у меня встречный вопрос: как вы себе представляете работу

```
void vector_filling(RanIT from, RanIT to, size_t n)
```

Если у вас уже есть начальный и конечный итераторы - зачем вам `n`? Если конечного итератора нет - то что вы передаете? Какой смысл в *каждой* итерации делать `resize`? Да и сравнивать итераторы лучше на равенство. Еще - у вас итераторы идут как параметр шаблона, а генератор - строго `double`. Почему не получать этот тип из типа итератора, например? Или хотя бы дать его как параметр шаблона?

Есть и другие вопросы, но ограничусь пока этими. Вопросы не риторические, но ответьте на них самому себе - это как намеки, что код можно *существенно* улучшить.

Comment: Но, если, я использую этот генератор в такой функции, он заполняется случайными числами template <typename RanIT>
void vector_filling(RanIT from, RanIT to, size_t n, Uniform <double>& gen)
{
    for (auto it = from; it < to; ++it)
    {
        vector <double> coordinates(n);
        for (size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i)
            coordinates[i] = gen();
        *it = coordinates;
    }
}

Comment: Что это за ерунда вообще? по выходу из цикла у вас нет никакого вектора. И потом, я не понимаю, что вы хотите этим сказать - *если, я использую этот генератор в такой функции, он заполняется случайными числами* - это подтверждение ответа, отрицание? Сформулируйте внятно и точно.